# How to export result of select statement in prestodb.io

Tags: presto

Two things.

1. How can I execute an sql statement without "presto-cli-0.56-executable.jar", for example I want to provide a web interface where people could write query and see the output on web
2. How to export the result of the select statement into a file?

Answer (score 30):

Simple answer :

```
presto --execute "select * from foo" --output-format CSV > foo.csv
```

You can use these formats :

```
ALIGNED
VERTICAL
CSV
TSV
CSV_HEADER
TSV_HEADER
```

Comment: how to configure the connection?

Comment: -f option allows you to run a query in a file. See https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/current/installation/cli.html

Answer (score 15):

For completeness, you can run the presto cli client like so

```
presto --server {server_name}:{server_port} --catalog {catalog_name} --schema {schema_name} --user {user_name} --execute "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1" --output-format CSV > output_fname.csv
```

And if you want the header to be included, use the following as hinted by answers above

```
--output-format CSV_HEADER
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you enter the password ? If I put --password as an argument, it just waits forever for user input

Comment: @d-_-b you can set TRINO_PASSWORD envt variable to avoid password prompt. refer https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/cli.html?highlight=csv#authentication

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/kR-3YZAaNg8